# Access returned computed array within method and manipulate

Tags: arrays, methods, foreach, vue.js, computed-properties

I have a computed array which is full of tags and updates depending on what selection i make in the select box. I would like to take this array and pass it to a method and then run a method to update what “results” have an active class. Although I get an array saying I can’t run forEach on this element.

Been through a few topics and understand computed properties dont work like that but surely there is a way around this.

https://jsfiddle.net/39jb3fzw/6/

**Short Snippet**

```
methods: {
        updateOutput() {
          var tags = this.tagArray;
          tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            console.log(tag);
          })
        }
    },
    computed: {
        concatenated: function () {
            var ret = this.selected.concat(this.selected2, this.selected3);
            this.tagArray = ret;
            //this.updateOutput();
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

**Full Output**

https://jsfiddle.net/39jb3fzw/6/

Thanks again :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the line:

`var ret = this.selected.concat(this.selected2, this.selected3);`

That line of code is returning an empty string rather than an array. This is because `this.selectedX` is a string rather than an Array. This explains why `tag.forEach` is undefined. `forEach` doesn't exist on the String prototype.

You can create this an array instead be doing

`var ret = [ this.selected, this.selected2, this.selected3 ]`

From there you can set `this.tagArray` to `ret`

Hope this helps